# How to send message in a Discord Thread?

Tags: python, discord.py

So I need to create and send messages in discord thread. I have been able to create threads but unable to send message in them. I am using Discord.py library (v2.0 supports thread).

```
await ctx.channel.create_thread(name="Thread" , type=discord.ChannelType.public_thread )
```

This is what I am using to create thread. I have no lead on how to send message in it. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`create_thread()` returns the thread created, so you can just call `send()` from it.

```
thread = await ctx.channel.create_thread(name="Thread" , type=discord.ChannelType.public_thread )
await thread.send("This message is sent to the created thread!")
```